# Can't find the documentation for \tikzstyle or `+=` operator in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I've noticed in a number of examples that the following is occasionally used when working with `tikz`:

```
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
```

When I search the documentation I can't find anything about this particular syntax.  I can find no documentation for either `\tikzstyle` or `+=`.

I'm guessing that this means something like

```
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
```

Could someone explain what this syntax is about and where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: have you seen [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372) ? Could be relevant/helpful...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't find an explanation for this command in newer versions of PGF/TikZ because is an old syntax which has been replaced with `\tikzset`; it's not very fortunate that that the manual for version 3.0 still contains this syntax in some of the examples. If you have the manual for version 1.18! (I found a version [here](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf)), you'll find it on page 81 and, yes, you're right, the plus sign is the same as `append style` in the new syntax:

[image]

For more information about using `\tikzset` versus `\tikzstyle`, you can see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372).